# How to dissassemble Cypress MCU based firmware?

Tags: disassembly, firmware

I have a firmware in bin format belongs to Cypress CY7C638xx based gadget.
This chip is Low Speed USB Peripheral Controller containing a 8-bit MCU.

I would like to analyse that firmware to reverse it. I could not find any disassembler for that target.

I am planning to dissassemble byte by byte using instruction set. I know it is very tedious and cumborsome work and prone to errors.

Is there another better way?

Answer (score 1):

doesn't the CY7C638xx have a M8C CPU? When so, did you try this project:

[M8cdis - A disassembler for the Cypress PSoC 1 M8C processor family](https://github.com/jcwren/m8cdis)

It seems older, but the instruction set should still be the same.